# Certificates for Session Hosts on RDS Deployment

Tags: windows-server-2016, remote-desktop-services, rds

I have a RDS Deployment in Windows Server 2019 compose of 3 servers:

1 host with the Connection Broker, RDS Gateway, RD Webclient and License server

The other 2 servers are the session hosts.

I hace configured the SSL certificate for the Gateway, Webclient and Conection Broker, but should I install the same certificate on the session hosts? Or the session hosts needs ti have their own certificate with their hostname (fqdn)?

Regards,
Amedina

Answer (score 2):

They need to have their own certificate, when I connect to the gateway everything is ok because the cert matches the public FQDN published for the GW server. But then when the RDGW redirects connection to the host after CAP and RAP, a warning pops up regarding a certificate issue and I can see that the RDSH certificate is self signed and the domain is the local (DC) FQDN for the host.